# Avoid overwriting an excel sheet on sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

Do you have a workaround solution to avoid overwriting an Excel file in `SharePoint`? I know about the "check out" one and the permission. Is there anything else?

Comment: Improved formatting

Answer (score 0):

If the file name exist, SharePoint will overwrite the file, you can turn on versioning in order to keep the previous file